# Recognize the product key after a clone?

Tags: windows-10, uefi, clone, product-key

With windows 10, after a clone in legacy mode, do the PC recognize the product key on the bios by itself or do I need to run the clone in uefi mode to recognize the product key?

Comment: Here's a reference link to tomshardware https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/disk-cloning-will-product-key-follow.3344921/

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS product key will only be useful if it is for the same version of Windows.

Meaning that if you are moving Windows 10 to a computer that was originally
bought with Windows 8, this will not work, since the OEM BIOS key can only be used
for the automatic activation of Windows 8.
(Microsoft does not freely upgrade to Windows 10 any more.)

You should do the clone in the same firmware mode as on the target computer.
It will have a better chance of working if both computers are of the same type,
UEFI or Legacy,
since I don't see how otherwise it is possible for the cloning to work.